# libxmljs: how to use xinclude?

Tags: node.js, xml, xsd, libxml-js

I try to use libxmljs with nodejs.
In my sample I want to use the xi:include.

```
    <ord:order  xmlns:ord="http://example.org/ord"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.org/ord chapter04ord1.xsd"
      xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
      <number>123ABBCC123</number>
      <customer>
        <name>Priscilla Walmsley</name>
        <number>15466</number>
      </customer>
      <items>
        <xi:include href="/Users/mar/ws_e/libxml/test/resources/chapter5prod.xml" />
      </items>
    </ord:order>
```

include File:

```
<ord:product  xmlns:ord="http://example.org/ord"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.org/ord chapter04ord1.xsd">
    <number>557</number>
    <name>Short-Sleeved Linen Blouse</name>
    <size system="US-DRESS">10</size>
    <color value="blue"/>
</ord:product>
```

This is my code:

```
    var xsdDoc = libxml.parseXml(schemaSource);
    var xmlDocValid = libxml.parseXml(docSource);
    var xmlDocInvalid = libxml.parseXml(xml_invalid);
    xmlDocValid.validate(xsdDoc);

    console.dir(xmlDocValid);
    console.dir(xmlDocValid.validationErrors);
```

Then I get the error:

```
Document {
  errors: [],
  validationErrors: 
    [ { Error: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude}include': This element is not expected. Expected is ( product ).
```

So my question is how to use the x:include right at libxmljs?

Kind regards

Markus

Comment: See "XInclude is not working": https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-xml-validator.

Comment: Thanks. So, did you find a proper working workaround?

Comment: I think you should not use XInclude at all with libxmljs. Assemble the parts of your XML documents in other ways.